# Support PHP Syntax Highlighting in CSS Files in vscode

Tags: php, css, visual-studio-code

I extend one of my CSS stylesheets with PHP code, such as:

```php
<?php
    include_once '../config.inc.php';
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000");
?>
#something {
    max-width: <?php echo GRAPH_MAX_WIDTH; ?>px;
}
```

While this works fine vscode kind of panics on the PHP part when validating my CSS file.

Is there a way to make vscode ignore any PHP in CSS files? Of course, I could disable CSS validation completely but I'd rather avoid that.

*Sidemark:* I don't think using PHP in my CSS stylesheet is a performance issue here. I only use it to insert quasi-static values from a config file.

Comment: "I don't think using PHP in my CSS stylesheet is a performance issue here" — Since your PHP doesn't generate any cache control headers it means the browser will re-request the CSS a lot when it doesn't need to. That's a performance issue.

Comment: Good point @Quentin, I added a cache control header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don’t you use CSS variables if your variables are static. If it is not working for you, then SCSS is the solution for your situation.

By the way, using php inside css is always have performance issue. Static files (html, css, js) has much faster than any dynamically created html, css, js files as there will be extra step of compiling the dynamic code in the server side.

Comment: Although you're right, this is not answering the OP's question: how to highlight the PHP syntax or make vscode ignore it at all.

Comment: You are right. But what he does is already bad practice, and CSS already has solution itself for what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: While this does not answer my question, it solves my problem, thank you! I didn't know about CSS variables yet.